# What does scaffolding files for drupal/core do when I do a composer require <module>?

Tags: 9, composer

I noticed that default.settings.php files gets copied to scaffold folder:

Copy [web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php from assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php

Why is it copying this file to scaffold and what is it the purpose of this?

Comment: So that boilerplate files stay updated with Drupal core releases (they do sometimes change) and or are replaced if they are deleted by mistake. You can configure this behavior in composer.json.

Comment: https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold explains itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The purpose of scaffolding files is to allow Drupal sites to be fully
> managed by Composer, and still allow individual asset files to be
> placed in arbitrary locations.

From: https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold

The reason that `default.settings.php` is copied across is that this file is not part of the Drupal core (the contents of `/web/core`), nor is it part of a module, theme, or distribution. But it's part of a base Drupal installation, so Composer copies it to the correct location upon install.